# Django : is there a way to create a popup window without the use of a template file?

Tags: django, popup

I'm accessing instruments from a Django application (sorry if I don't use the right terms I am not a developper).

One of the instrument we use must do the same measurement a few times : Once the instrument has made an acquisition, the user must do some things, inform the application, so it can starts the next acquisition.

I wanted to make everything from the view to make it simpler.

So basically I need to make a popup window before the acquisition, and wait for the user to close this window to start the acquisition.

The messages from django need some lines in the template, but I'd like to do all this before accessing the template ?

Is that possible ?

Thank you for your answers !

Comment: Sorry but your question isn't clear. There's no code showing what you're doing, no description of which view and which template you're talking about. I have no idea what a "popup window" is for you, is it a new browser window, or just a dialog covering the current content within the page? Please read [ask] to understand better how to right a good question on SO.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see you're a new contributor, so I advise you to check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'm sorry if this isn't clear, first time asking on SO. If I don't have any code to show you, it's because I have no idea on how to do this. But here is how the structure would look : In my views.py, I have a method defined, that will look for the instrument using serial protocols, then in a for loop I would make a popup window (a message window to ask the user to click ok once he has done the necessary with the instrument), then still in the loop it would make the acquisition. I can't do this in a template because as far as I've understand I can't really use serial protocal in a template.

Comment: what I mean by popup window is this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X16CV.png

Comment: The simplest way I see here is to pass the index of the for loop in the url, and having the popup window in the template. I wanted to avoid that but I don't see any other means.